# Is there a faster way to query a remote filesystem with WMI?

Tags: c#, .net, wmi, directory-listing, system.management

I am trying to recursively get all of the files — 5 or 6 files give or take — under the directory `C:\YC`.  I am bound to one WMI call to a remote computer.

I managed to do this call using the WQL `LIKE` operator but it's taking around 30 seconds, even though the result is around 6 files:

```csharp
// USING A WQL QUERY
string query = "SELECT Name,LastModified FROM CIM_DataFile WHERE PATH LIKE '\\\\YC\\\\%' AND DRIVE ='C:'";
ObjectQuery oQuery = new ObjectQuery();
oQuery.QueryString = query;

ManagementObjectSearcher oSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, oQuery);
oSearcher.Options.Rewindable = false;

// Takes long time
ManagementObjectCollection oReturnCollection = oSearcher.Get();

// SHOWING EACH FILE
foreach (ManagementObject oReturn in oReturnCollection)
{
     Console.WriteLine(oReturn["Name"]?.ToString());
}
```

Is there a more efficient way using `System.Management` objects to get the files recursively (with or without WQL, but with one WMI call)?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that using WMI to query the filesystem is very slow when using the `LIKE` operator to filter on the `Name`/`Path` property, even if the filter value doesn't contain a wildcard (`%`).

This will take more than one query, but you can get the [`CIM_Directory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/cim-directory) (actually [`Win32_Directory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-directory)) instance for your base directory and traverse the hierarchy yourself...

```csharp
static void EnumerateDirectory(ManagementObject directory, bool recurse)
{
    // Get all related CIM_LogicalFile instances where this is the parent (GroupComponent)
    // and the related instance is the child (PartComponent)
    using (ManagementObjectCollection children = directory.GetRelated("CIM_LogicalFile", null, null, null, "PartComponent", "GroupComponent", false, null))
        foreach (ManagementObject child in children.Cast<ManagementObject>())
            switch (child.Path.ClassName)
            {
                case "CIM_Directory":
                case "Win32_Directory":
                    Console.WriteLine($"Directory: { child["Name"] }");
                    if (recurse)
                        EnumerateDirectory(child, true);
                    break;
                case "CIM_DataFile":
                    Console.WriteLine($"     File: { child["Name"] }");
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine($"ERROR: Unexpected { child.Path.ClassName } instance.  This should never happen!");
                    break;
            }
}
```

That's calling [`GetRelated()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.management.managementobject.getrelated) to get all [`CIM_LogicalFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/cim-logicalfile) instances [associated with](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/associators-of-statement) `directory`; `CIM_LogicalFile` is the parent class of `CIM_DataFile` and `CIM_Directory`, which itself is the parent of `Win32_Directory`.  We could call the simpler `directory.GetRelated("CIM_LogicalFile")` overload but that would return one `CIM_Directory` instance we don't want: the parent directory.  Instead, we call that longer overload that allows us to specify that we want `directory` to be the parent in the `CIM_Directory` ⇔ `CIM_Directory` relationship.

You would call `EnumerateDirectory()` like this...

```csharp
static void Main()
{
    const string directoryPath = @"C:\YC";
    ObjectQuery directoryQuery = new SelectQuery(
        "CIM_Directory",
        $"Name = \"{ directoryPath.Replace(@"\", @"\\") }\""
    );

    using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(directoryQuery))
    using (ManagementObjectCollection results = searcher.Get())
    using (ManagementObject directory = results.Cast<ManagementObject>().SingleOrDefault())
    {
        if (directory == null)
            Console.WriteLine($"ERROR: The query ' { directoryQuery.QueryString } ' returned no results.");
        else
            EnumerateDirectory(directory, true);
    }
}
```

If you only want the immediate child files in a directory that code is much simpler...

```cs
static void EnumerateFiles(ManagementObject directory)
{
    using (ManagementObjectCollection children = directory.GetRelated("CIM_DataFile"))
        foreach (ManagementObject child in children.Cast<ManagementObject>())
            Console.WriteLine($"File: { child["Name"] }");
}
```