# WMI with System.Management: Get files filtered by criteria and without using WQL

Tags: c#, .net, wmi, directory-listing, system.management

I am trying to get files filtered by a path and extension via WMI using System.Management with C#.

I DO NOT want to use WQL (WMI Query) - (because its very slow for my purpuses)

I know how to get ALL CIM_DataFile objects, but I want to filter them BEFORE they are returned to the ManagementObjectCollection collection, otherwise I am getting a very long list which takes forever to run

Here is the code:

```
        ManagementPath path = new ManagementPath("CIM_DataFile");
        ManagementClass file_class = new ManagementClass(path);

        // I want to add a filter here which will add a filter to GetInstances()
        ManagementObjectCollection File_objects_collection = file_class.GetInstances();

        foreach (ManagementObject file in File_objects_collection)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(file["Name"].ToString());
        }
```

Thank you

Comment: If you want to get all instances of a class that match a filter, it has to be done using a `SELECT` query with a `WHERE` clause.  Whether you write the query yourself or let the `System.Management` classes compose it for you, a WQL query will be executed.  My answer to your earlier question shows how to do this with better performance.  Does this answer your question? [Is there a faster way to query a remote filesystem with WMI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70286799/is-there-a-faster-way-to-query-a-remote-filesystem-with-wmi)

Comment: Is this a followup question to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70286799/is-there-a-faster-way-to-query-a-remote-filesystem-with-wmi? Might want to edit your post to include that reference and make it clear what the difference is in this question.